# User privacy setting Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel but I must say I am enjoying it a lot. I have got a task in hand in which i have to crete DB for user (Of Course Like other web app), in which user have privacy setting as they need. For example if a user creates a new post user can choose either he/she can share among there friends, public or make it private.  What I cannot decide is:

> **Do I create a column inside user table and get the privacy setting**

Or

> **Does Laravel has some class that I can implement?**

What would be the ideal solution for the problem. I am currently using larval 4.2 version.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: laravel does not come up with a predefined solution for your issue, since it is not meant for blogging or cms in particular (though it can be used for that, of course). You will have to come up with a custom solution.

Comment: @nozzleman. Thank you for the comment i really appreciate it. I am not excepting that Laravel would have solution specific for me all I want to know is does Laravel have any plugins that i can implement. But you make it clear they don't. Thanks again

Comment: well, i guess there might be packages (which are kind of "plugins" for php/laravel) for blogging, cms etc and surely, some of those come up with privacy settings or similar. try searching at http://packalyst.com/ maybe you find a package that suits your need